# Apply date format in multiple dataframes

Tags: r, date, for-loop, lapply

I have 3 data frames, as shown in the code below.

```
code_1000 <-
  as.data.frame(cbind(
    c("3", "3", "7", "7", "7", "7", "2", "2", "4", "4"),
    c("344", "344", "73", "73", "71", "72", "21", "27", "42", "43"),
    c("9-02-2017", "10-01-2016","9-02-2014", "25-03-2015", "9-02-2017",
      "10-06-2017", "8-04-2017", "25-08-2016", "07-08-2017", "15-11-2016"
    )
  ))
code_2430 <-
  as.data.frame(cbind(
    c("3", "3", "7", "7", "7", "7", "2", "2", "4", "4"),
    c("344", "344", "73", "73", "71", "72", "21", "27", "42", "43"),
    c("9-02-2017", "10-01-2016","9-02-2014", "25-03-2015", "9-02-2017",
      "10-06-2017", "8-04-2017", "25-08-2016", "07-08-2017", "23-09-2016"
    )
  ))
code_3453 <-
  as.data.frame(cbind(
    c("3", "3", "7", "7", "7", "7", "2", "2", "4", "4"),
    c("344", "344", "73", "73", "71", "72", "21", "27", "42", "43"),
    c("9-02-2017", "10-01-2016","9-02-2014", "25-03-2015", "9-02-2017",
      "10-06-2017", "8-04-2017", "25-08-2016", "07-08-2017", "13-06-2016"
    )
  ))
names(code_1000) <- c("number", "code", "date")
names(code_2430) <- c("number", "code", "date")
names(code_3453) <- c("number", "code", "date")
```

I want to apply a date format on the column `date` of each dataframe (`code_1000`, `code_2430` and `code_3453`). 
The desired date format is:

```
   code_1000$date<-lubridate::dmy(as.character(code_1000$date)
```

Which gives a date format "yyyy-mm-dd" as output (see figure in the link below).

[image]

The code above shows 3 samples to make it simpler. Actually I have 50 dataframes, and I am using Shiny to plot some scatter graphs, which the x axis is the date column.

USing `for`, I tried the following code:

```
 list<- as.data.frame(c("1000","2430","3453"))
    names(list) <- c("code.ID") # list of the codes dataframes ID

    date.format<-function(df){
    lubridate::dmy(as.character(df[,"date"]))
    }  # function to apply the desired date format

    for (m in 1:nrow(list)){
      loop.df<-eval(parse(text=paste0("code_",list$code.ID[m]))) # for each m, it returns a code_xxxx date frame

    assign(loop.df[,3],date.format(loop.df)) # apply the date format on the dataframe, storing the results
    }
```

I got the following error:

```
Error in `[.default`(loop.df, , 3) : incorrect number of dimensions
```

When I apply the isolated date.format function on the dateframes, it works fine.

I would like to learn how to do this using `for` and `lapply()` function, as I have read that in R `lapply()` is an easier approach most of times.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: i made an edit, as it was not `shiny` related. `assing()` does not take an array as you attempt it. And you should have a look at `list()` instead,..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<rant on>` I've been trying to get people to abandon the `as.data.frame(cbind(...))` strategy for years. It forces everything to be the same atomic type and then when that type happens to be character the results is all factors. A big mess in my opinion. In this case there is a `dmy` method for factors, but some authors have not provided for that typical user expectation`<rant off>` (Just use `data.frame()`.)

Assemble the items with the first 5 characters "code_" in a character vector and then loop over them to build a list. Then loop (with `lapply` again) over that list of R objects to convert the 3rd column to date format:

```
> objects(pattern="code_.+")
[1] "code_1000" "code_2430" "code_3453"
> obj_list <- lapply(objects(pattern="code_.+"), get)
> str(obj_list)
List of 3
 $ :'data.frame':   10 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ number: Factor w/ 4 levels "2","3","4","7": 2 2 4 4 4 4 1 1 3 3
  ..$ code  : Factor w/ 8 levels "21","27","344",..: 3 3 8 8 6 7 1 2 4 5
  ..$ date  : Factor w/ 9 levels "07-08-2017","10-01-2016",..: 9 2 8 5 9 3 7 6 1 4
 $ :'data.frame':   10 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ number: Factor w/ 4 levels "2","3","4","7": 2 2 4 4 4 4 1 1 3 3
  ..$ code  : Factor w/ 8 levels "21","27","344",..: 3 3 8 8 6 7 1 2 4 5
  ..$ date  : Factor w/ 9 levels "07-08-2017","10-01-2016",..: 9 2 8 5 9 3 7 6 1 4
 $ :'data.frame':   10 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ number: Factor w/ 4 levels "2","3","4","7": 2 2 4 4 4 4 1 1 3 3
  ..$ code  : Factor w/ 8 levels "21","27","344",..: 3 3 8 8 6 7 1 2 4 5
  ..$ date  : Factor w/ 9 levels "07-08-2017","10-01-2016",..: 9 2 8 5 9 3 7 6 1 4

> obj_list <- lapply(obj_list , function(dfrm) {                  
                      dfrm[[3]] <- lubridate::dmy(as.character(dfrm[,"date"]))
                      dfrm} )
> str(obj_list)
List of 3
 $ :'data.frame':   10 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ number: Factor w/ 4 levels "2","3","4","7": 2 2 4 4 4 4 1 1 3 3
  ..$ code  : Factor w/ 8 levels "21","27","344",..: 3 3 8 8 6 7 1 2 4 5
  ..$ date  : Date[1:10], format: "2017-02-09" "2016-01-10" ...
 $ :'data.frame':   10 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ number: Factor w/ 4 levels "2","3","4","7": 2 2 4 4 4 4 1 1 3 3
  ..$ code  : Factor w/ 8 levels "21","27","344",..: 3 3 8 8 6 7 1 2 4 5
  ..$ date  : Date[1:10], format: "2017-02-09" "2016-01-10" ...
 $ :'data.frame':   10 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ number: Factor w/ 4 levels "2","3","4","7": 2 2 4 4 4 4 1 1 3 3
  ..$ code  : Factor w/ 8 levels "21","27","344",..: 3 3 8 8 6 7 1 2 4 5
  ..$ date  : Date[1:10], format: "2017-02-09" "2016-01-10" ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It worked. The final result was a list of 50 elements, with the date format desired. Now, I would like to convert each element into a dataframe, keeping the original name of each element. For instance, in the sample codes above, I would like the first element of the output to be de a dataframe called code_1000, the second one to be a dataframe code_2430, and so on, keeping the column names (number, code and date). In other words, I want to override the previous `code_xxxx` date column with the new formated one. Thank you again!

Comment: It seems to work:
`for (m in 1:length(obj.code)){ 
  assign( paste0(obj.bind[[m]]),obj_list[[m]])
  }`
where `obj.code <-objects(pattern="code_.+")`

Comment: @GuilhermeFagundes : May work but is likely to be quite inefficient. Try to avoid using `assign`. R is rather inefficient when used as a macro language.